# Issue writing PDF content to S3

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to write a PDF file to S3 using node.js

The file contains non-ascii contents.

I tried writing:
1) using readstream , and specifying Body as this readstream for s3.putobject
2) fs.readfile , and specifying Body as this the file-data for s3.putobject

I do not find node js equivalent of upload_file in python
s3.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Issue is :  The non-ascii contents are not written to S3 file

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Puneet, here is the code

https://github.com/sawaikar-gauri/html-to-pdf-serverless

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload as buffer instead of stream.

```
pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
    console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
});
```

And use this buffer inside params

```
var params = {
    Body: <File Buffer>,
};
```

Comment: This as wel fails